# Reversing loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my exercise. I have to draw something like this:
https://screenshots.firefox.com/3qaHB7dcr3n610hi/jsbin.com

And this is my code

```
  var empty = "";
for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  empty += "*";
  console.log(empty)
}
```

but with this code I can only make this:

```
*  
**
***
****
*****
```

I have no idea how to reverse this loop to start it from top from 5 stars, i tried something like this:

```
var empty = "";
for (i = 5; i <= 0;i--) {
  empty+="*";
  console.log(empty);
}
```

But doesn't work. Anybody know how to do this? I will be grateful :)

Comment: your condition is wrong. Should be ` i >= 0`

Comment: although that won't change the output since you still start with an empty string

Comment: i changed my condition, but still have problem with the second loop

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a beginner's coding school. You're supposed to exhaust every single other resource first, starting with google.

Comment: check out this fiddle mate:  https://jsfiddle.net/94La3y77/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition was wrong. Check this.

```js
for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  console.log('\"' + '*'.repeat(i) + '\"');
}
for(let i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
  console.log('\"' + '*'.repeat(i) + '\"');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Your approach builds the first part.
- The second part can be accomplished using the function **[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)** in descending  direction.

```js
var empty = "";
var i = 0;

// Build the first part
for (; i < 5; i++) {
  empty += "*";
  console.log(empty)
}

// Here i = 5, so this is the initialization for the following loop.
// Loop in descending direction using the function slice.
for (; i > 0; i--) {  
  console.log(empty.slice(0, i))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How is this useful to somebody who cannot construct a for loop?

Comment: nice one all the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `for/loop` you could use a `while` loop to change the direction:

```js
let stars = 0;
let count = 0;
while (count < 9) {
  if (count < 5) stars++;
  if (count >= 5) stars--;
  const line = Array(stars).fill('*').join('');
  console.log(line);
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need a nested for loop. (As some exercises sometimes do)

```js
var k = 0;
for(var i = 1; i < 12; i++){   
    var stx = "";
    for(var j = k; j < i; j++){
        stx += "*";
    }
    if(i > 5) k += 2
    if(i == 6) continue
    console.log(stx);
}
```